# Валидация данных MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, mvc, валидация, модель-данных

### Описание проблемы

Добрый день, дорогие форумчане! 
Сижу уже 30 минут и ломаю себе голову, все до этого представления принимали валидацию, и если поля были пустые или не соответствовали условию - выдавало сообщение об ошибке под этим полем. И тут я дошел до Edit представления, где изменяю поля о пользователе в базе данных. Но в Edit валидацию просто игнорирует, и я смело могу оставить поля Фамилия или Имя пустыми...

***Какую маленькую строку кода я упустил?(***

### Модель

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} - обязательное поле")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Значение {0} должно содержать не менее {2} символов.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} - обязательное поле")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Значение {0} должно содержать не менее {2} символов.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Аватар")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

### Контроллер

```
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit()
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

            if (user != null)
            {
                EditModel model = new EditModel
                {
                    Name = user.Name,
                    Surname = user.Surname,
                    Image = user.Image,
                };

                return View(model);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditModel model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.Name = model.Name;
                user.Surname = model.Surname;

                if (uploadImage != null)
                {
                    byte[] imageData = null;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
                        imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
                    user.Image = imageData;
                }

                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Что-то пошло не так");
            }

            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователь не найден");

            return View(model);
        }
```

### Представление

```
@model KryshtopWEB.Models.EditModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Редактирование учетной записи";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h3>@ViewBag.Title</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Применить изменения" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="file" name="uploadImage" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                @if (Model.Image != null)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("<img class=\"img-rounded\" style=\"height:auto; width:200px; max-height:100%\" src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                        + Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image) + "\" />")
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="~/Content/no_picture.png" class="img-rounded" style="height:auto; width:200px; max-height:100%;">
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте подключен ли jquery.validate.js для валидации на клиенте.

Стандартно подключается через `Bundle`(BundleConfig), подключается на страницу так `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Должно быть что-то вроде

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
...
```

Comment: Отец, но проблему уже давно решил) Ты был прав.